# Xtext How to auto build referenced language

Tags: xtext

I use 2 different DSL languages in my Project and reference them like described in this tutorial:

http://christiandietrich.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/xtext-referencing-elements-of-one-dsl-from-another-dsl/

My question is:
How to configure the build of the second language, to also rebuild the referenced first language?

If I choose 'Generate Xtext Artifacts' in the second language it should also trigger the workflow to rebuild the first one.

Answer (score 0):

you can have multiple language sections in one workflow (have a look at Xtexts Xbase Project). but i dont see the usecase for that in your constellation

Comment: my problem is, that if someone adds changes in the "define" language of the example, these changes are not included if the "use" language is rebuilt. So I want to automatically rebuild the "define" language everytime the "use" language is built.

Comment: What about using maven?